# jQuery Validator Unbinding

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the [jQuery Validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). And I'm trying to figure out: **How can I un-attach the validator from my form once its submitted?**

```
$(function() {
  // Just the rules, etc...
  validator = $("#sweepstakesForm").validate({rules: {fname: {required: true,minlength: 2,maxlength: 50},lname: {required: true,minlength: 2,maxlength: 50},email: {email: true,remote: "?c=home&m=jsHook&param=email&nojson=1",required: true,minlength: 6,maxlength: 120},address: {required: true,minlength: 5,maxlength: 100},state_0: {required: true},state:  ); // etc ...

  $('#sweepstakesForm').submit() {

  }
});
```

I have tried these to no avail:

```
validator = null;
$("#sweepstakesForm").unbind('validate');
delete validator;
```

Comment: Took a quick look at [the source](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js) and from what I can see, there is no method to un-attach/destroy the validator.

Comment: Why _exactly_ are you trying to kill the validator?  Once a form is validated and submitted, you're either on a new page, the submit button is disabled, or the form is disabled/hidden...  killing the validator is a moot point.  Perhaps if we knew more, we'd be able to suggest a workaround.

Comment: one sure way would be reload whole form as new html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
$('#sweepstakesForm').data('validator', null);
$("#sweepstakesForm").unbind('validate');
```

Comment: The first one "works" for me too, but perhaps only because it gives an error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of null` [line 332 of jquery.validate.1.11.1.js](https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/6249726), if you re-enter invalid data after resetting the form.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Also, considering this is a two year old answer it's worth pointing out that i've tested this and can confirm it works on `jQuery 1.7.2`.

Comment: As an aside, [as of jQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/#entry-longdesc) `off()` is preferred to `unbind()`.

Comment: I looked through the source code and it turns out there's a destroy() method that does this: `this.resetForm(); $(this.currentForm).off(".validate").removeData("validator");`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an `.unbind('submit')`

```
$('#sweepstakesForm').submit(function () {
    $(this).unbind('submit');
});
```

Comment: That's not what he asked.  He wants to kill the validator.

Comment: @Sparky672, it's an interesting answer though. Presumably the validator has bound to submit events, and unbinding all submit handlers should effectively stop further validation. But I'm guessing it's a minefield of side-effects.

Comment: Thank you for posting a comment, the unbind was not exactly was I was looking for, but I appreciate the comment!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with this plugin, but from the documentation it looks like what you want is:

```
$('#sweepstakesForm').rules('remove');
```

Comment: Its not what i was looking for but ill keep this on the back burner, thank you!

Comment: @JREAM, does it not prevent further validation? From my reading of the docs, it seems to do what you've asked for, maybe you can explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Hello from 2020 :) My validator version is still 1.11.1 and none of the code snippets above worked properly (without errors in console). The one that did is:

```
$('form,input,select,textarea,button').attr("novalidate", "novalidate").attr("formnovalidate", "formnovalidate")
```

I know it affects many elements on the page, but for debugging its fine IMHO.